# Block with #markup urls

Tags: routes

I have a very big content written as a Basic Page where i want to construct a block with a menu tree structure next to it, in order to let users to click on a link and to guide them to the appropriate section of this huge article. Imagine that there will be some  tags with a specific "id" next to a section of the content for example. How can i implement this and what approaches should i follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom block to only show on that page in full html with links to that content... should work.